# How to ignore zero padding for parsing the timezone offset using Chrono in Rust?

Tags: datetime, parsing, rust, rust-chrono

I want to parse the following example string with Chrono: `"03:00 +3"` where `+3` is the timezone offset, i.e. the format `%#z` or `%:::z` but without leading zeros.

I have already tried the format specifiers

- `%z`, `%:z`, `%::z`, `%:::z` and `%#z`
- `%-z`, `%-:z`, `%-::z`, `%-:::z` and `%-#z`

but I always get either `premature end of input` or `bad or unsupported format string` errors.

How can I specify this format?

Answer (score 1):

Answer on Github: https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/issues/1055

"It is currently not possible. [...]"